# Unit-Distance Polyhedra

Tags: discrete-geometry, graph-colorings, polyhedra

What polyhedra are known to have two vertices adjacent if and only if they are of distance $d$ apart, for fixed $d$? For example, regular Platonic solids satisfy this condition, so I am looking for other "regular" non-Platonic solids.

Related question: has work been done to consider the chromatic number of these regular polyhedra?

Answer (score 3):

The *triangular bipyramid* glues two regular tetrahedra base-to-base:

---

[image: TriBiPyr]

---

The pairwise distances among the $5$ vertices are $1$,
except the two top/bot apexes are $2\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \approx 1.6$ apart.
So I think this meets your criterion of a non-Platonic polyhedron having

> two vertices adjacent if and only if they are of distance $d$ [$=1$] apart

I believe the same holds true of all the *[deltahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltahedron)*.

Comment: More generally, the convex solids all of whose faces are regular polygons: prisms and antiprisims, Platonic solids, Archimedean (symmetry group acts transitively on the vertices) and Johnson solids (everything else).

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem could be useful for you, "Choombam"s are other types with your conditions:

http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h111388p632753